# SSH public key authentication works on LAN and not from WAN

Tags: ssh, osx, authentication, raspbian

I've setup my SSH server to use public key authentication. When I connect to my server on local network, it authenticates. But it doesn't when I connect over the internet.

I don't think the problem is port forwarding. It used to work before disabling password login in the server.

Here is the output of ssh -vvv user@example.com

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to example.com [1.2.3.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.52
debug1: no match: dropbear_0.52
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [example.com]:22
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[example.com]:22" from file "/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 132/256
debug2: bits set: 501/1024
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 10:21:9f:80:7b:a3:94:0d:ca:3b:15:fd:e1:37:20:ee
debug3: put_host_port: [1.2.3.4]:22
debug3: put_host_port: [example.com]:22
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[example.com]:22" from file "/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[1.2.3.4]:22" from file "/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[example.com]:22' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: bits set: 534/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fc0336004b0),
debug2: key: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@example.com's password:
```

and here my server's sshd_config:

```
# Package generated configuration file# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

If it's at all useful, my server is Raspbian and my client is OS X Mavericks

EDIT: the permission of the ~/.ssh directory in the server is set to 700. The authorized_keys file is set to 600.

EDIT: Log of internal connection:

```
$ ssh 192.168.2.145 -l user -vvv                                                                                                          [14:48:01]
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.145 [192.168.2.145] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.2.145]:22
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[192.168.2.145]:22" from file "/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 128/256
debug2: bits set: 514/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 12:1b:b5:5b:ab:f9:55:ed:e9:e9:56:cf:8c:a1:4c:4e
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.2.145]:22
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.2.145]:22
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[192.168.2.145]:22" from file "/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[192.168.2.145]:22" from file "/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[192.168.2.145]:22' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 534/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7ffeda40b940),
debug2: key: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 8e:81:e9:af:21:99:69:37:61:69:3a:76:b9:42:00:00
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 8e:81:e9:af:21:99:69:37:61:69:3a:76:b9:42:00:00
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.2.145 ([192.168.2.145]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env __CHECKFIX1436934
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env SECURITYSESSIONID
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env GREP_OPTIONS
debug3: Ignored env GREP_COLOR
debug3: Ignored env PAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESS
debug3: Ignored env LSCOLORS
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

Comment: Is this working with the same client machine but not going over the internet?

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" mean? What error message do you get? What is in your sshd logs?

Comment: @Timo yes. same client on local and external.

Comment: @JennyD The output on the post is when I connect over IP. I there anything else I should include?

Comment: Timo's answer is the correct one. I'd add that it's a bit confusing that you say "ssh doesn't connect" - it *does* connect, but your authentication fails.

Comment: @JennyD You're correct. I'll edit that.

Comment: Check if the autorized_keys file on the server contains something like e.g. `From=10.1.2.3" or some other IP address.

Comment: @JennyD it doesn't

Comment: could you add the log of a successful connection ?

Comment: @Kiwy I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had enabled SSH on my Tomato router on the same port. My connection attempt had been to the router, not to my host. I changed the ports and all is good.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2**:
You should consider t use the correct IP I don't know what you are trying but it is strange:
*Working*:
`debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.145 [192.168.2.145] port 22.

[...]

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4`

*Non working*:
`debug1: Connecting to example.com [1.2.3.4] port 22.

[...]

Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.52`

I bet your are connecting to the wrong ip and another deamon is answering you probably the one from you internet provider box and you should think to change ISP as enabling `sshd` on external IP for a provider box is not really secure.

*Extract from dropbear deamon home page*

> Dropbear is a relatively small SSH server and client. It runs on a variety of POSIX-based platforms. Dropbear is open source software, distributed under a MIT-style license. Dropbear is particularly useful for "embedded"-type Linux (or other Unix) systems, such as wireless routers.

[Source](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html)

---

**Edit 1**:
`OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011`
your ssh deamon has been compiled in 2011 ?
It doesn't seem realistic has you stated that you're using wheezy and OS X maverick.
Are you sure to authentify against the same deamon on you LAN and on the WAN ?

---

**Orignal Answer**
Your server use certificate and password authentication:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
```

But the computer your using outside does not provide et certificate :
`no such identity:/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa`

Your identity is not know by the server and certificate does not exist on your client so you fall back to user password authentication.

Have you try with the same computer from outside your network ?

Comment: I'm using rsa. And yes, I'm using the same computer inside and outside the network

Comment: are you using the same account on your client ?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to the same account from the same account, yes.

Comment: I'm using the default sshd that comes with raspbian. Apparently it was compiled in 2011.

Comment: are you using debian ? or rasbian ? that's not exactly the same

Comment: I'm using [raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/). It's based on debian wheezy.

Comment: I've edited the post. Does the difference matter though?

Comment: every detail metter, it can be a know bug of this particular version of SSH for example, (I don't thing it is) but the more you are precise and thorough the most the chance the real solution came up.

Comment: It's not the (remote) sshd daemon that was compiled in 2011 ("Edit #1"), it's the (local) ssh client on OSX.  The remote server (`OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4`) is from the current raspbian.

Comment: @goldilocks my mistake, but thing is there is a problem because the daemon answering from WAN is not the same as in LAN

Comment: Yeah, +1.  That is strange.   Dropbear is definitely not the pi.  But notice the key fails in both cases, the first one succeeds because of passwords.  The key is a bad key and probably has never worked.

Comment: No line 66 you can read        `debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[192.168.2.145]:22" from file "/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1`

Answer (score 1):

From the log it looks like your id_rsa ( you don't seem to have id_dsa at all) is not matching with the server.

I recommend you change the server back to accept passwords and then use `ssh-copy-id` to copy your id to to the server, then switch passwords back off.

Comment: When I use ssh-copy-id, I get "WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system."

Comment: Probably meaning the names match, but there's some lines that imply your public key is just bad (`Incorrect RSA1 identifier`, `Could not load "/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key`) but gets sent anyway.  I'd regenerate your keys from scratch and replace the old ones.