# How can I confirm the identity of the remote SSH host I'm trying to connect to?

Tags: ssh, raspbian

I'm trying to debug a [problem I have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109581/ssh-public-key-authentication-works-on-lan-and-not-from-wan) when trying to connect to an SSH host over WAN. I'm looking for a way to confirm that my client is reaching the correct host, and is not routed somewhere else along the way. I have access to both the client and he host. Maybe there a way to monitor every SSH connection request on the host's side to confirm that my request is actually reaching it?

The host is a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, SSH version is OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013.

Comment: @jasonwryan Yes. You can find it in the link I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things you can do:

1. Read the log files on the server. Which logfile will depend on how your system is configured; start by looking for `/var/log/secure` and `/var/log/messages`. If you can't find sshd logs there, check your syslog config for where `authpriv` messages go.
2. Check the SSH public key returned by the server. Do this by running the command

   `ssh-keyscan hostname > hostname-lan.pub` on the lan , and

   `ssh-keyscan hostname > hostname-wan.pub` on WAN.

   Then compare the two files (`diff hostname-lan.pub hostname-wan.pub`). If you're reaching the same server, there should be no difference. (Unless you're using different hostnames; in that case, the hostname will differ but the rest of the key will be the same.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Using `ssh-keyscan` showed me that when I connect through WAN, it connects to a dropbear server instead of an OpenSSH. Turns out I had enabled SSH on my Tomato router ages ago on the same port and had forgotten about it! I disabled SSH on the router, and all is good.

Comment: Hah, that explains why we couldn't figure out the problem in the other question! I should have thought of that...

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe there a way to monitor every SSH connection request on the host's side to confirm that my request is actually reaching it?

Yes, sshd will produce copious log output on the host which looks like:

```
Jan 26 13:49:55 Argon sshd[9928]: Connection from 1.2.3.4 port 42774
Jan 26 13:49:56 Argon sshd[9928]: Found matching DSA key: ...
Jan 26 13:49:56 Argon sshd[9928]: Postponed publickey for joseph from 1.2.3.4 port 42774 ssh2 [preauth]
Jan 26 13:49:56 Argon sshd[9928]: Found matching DSA key: ...
Jan 26 13:49:56 Argon sshd[9928]: Accepted publickey for joseph from 1.2.3.4 port 42774 ssh2
Jan 26 13:49:56 Argon sshd[9928]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user joseph by (uid=0)
Jan 26 13:49:56 Argon sshd[9928]: User child is on pid 9933
Jan 26 13:50:32 Argon sshd[9933]: Received disconnect from 1.2.3.4: 11: disconnected by user
Jan 26 13:50:32 Argon sshd[9928]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user joseph
```

By default, these messages are too low priority to show up in the standard Debian logs.  You may have to adjust either sshd or the syslog daemon accordingly.  If your Raspbian host is similar to my Debian machine (it should be), then create the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/everything.conf` with the contents:

```
*.info                       -/var/log/everything
```

This will cause all log messages of level info or above to appear in the file `/var/log/everything`.  This should give you output similar to my example above.